# HTML Input Element Error on Click for Java Script Function FormData JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, eclipse

Uncaught ReferenceError: saveFile is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (60000:403)
onclick @ 60000:403

```
function saveFile() {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
    console.log("form data " + formData);
    $.ajax({
        url : 'ajaxSaveFile.do',
        data : formData,
        processData : false,
        contentType : false,
        type : 'POST',
        success : function(data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error : function(err) {
            alert(err);
        }
    });
}
```

HTML

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i> Browse <input type="file" onClick="saveFile()" id = 'attachmentFileUploadInput' style="display: none;">
```

Comment: Did you import jquery lib before that?

Comment: Can you confirm the jquery lib I should have imported?

Comment: add the code at first and then try  `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>`